How to create a paged scroll view with peeking views in SwiftUI
I have a simple paging scroll view like this. This just circles with numbers in a paged horizontal scroll view.
struct PageView: View {
    var number: Int
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .padding(50)
            Text("\(number)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .foregroundStyle(.white)
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<5) { i in
                    PageView(number: i)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 5, span: 5, spacing: 0, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    }
}

I want the circles to peek out on both sides but stay centered as you scroll. Here's a start where I adjusted some of the properties, but I'm not sure how to make the page views still stayed centered in the scroll view as you page.
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 10) {
                ForEach(1..<5) { i in
                    PageView(number: i)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 5, span: 4, spacing: 0, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
            .padding(.leading, 40)
        }
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
    }
}


You should resize the ScrollView so that each "page" is not as wide as the screen. If you then do scrollClipDisabled, parts of other pages will be visible.
If you want half of the circles on each side to "peek out", the scroll view should occupy half of its container's width. You can resize the scroll view with containerRelativeFrame.
ScrollView(.horizontal) {
    HStack(spacing: 0) {
        ForEach(1..<5) { i in
            PageView(number: i)
                .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
        }
    }
}
.scrollTargetBehavior(.paging)
.containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal, count: 2, spacing: 0)
.scrollClipDisabled()

The proportion of the container's width that the scroll view takes up is span (default to 1) divided by count.
You can also just do a padding(.horizontal, someNumber) on the scroll view to let a constant width "peek out" from the other "pages".

Alternatively, use the viewAligned behaviour with contentMargin. You would need a GeometryReader if you want the circles on each side to "peek out" the same amount on every screen size.
GeometryReader { geo in
    // VStack and Spacers to align vertically center,
    // because GeometryReader messes up layout
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        ScrollView(.horizontal) {
            HStack(spacing: 0) {
                ForEach(1..<5) { i in
                    PageView(number: i)
                        // PageView should occupy half the width for half of circles on the sides to peek out
                        .frame(width: geo.size.width / 2)
                }
            }
            .scrollTargetLayout()
        }
        // content margins should be (geo.size.width - PageView.width) / 2
        .contentMargins(.horizontal, geo.size.width / 4, for: .scrollContent)
        // limitBehavior: .always to simulate a paging-like experience
        .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned(limitBehavior: .always))
        Spacer()
    }
}

However, a caveat of this approach is that the views will not be aligned when orientation changes.

Neat idea! It has some drawbacks for my use case. I would still like the whole screen to be swipe-able. The edges can't be swiped in this example. I also want to do some full-screen transitions for each page in the scroll view.

This modifier seems to add the desired effect but I can't figure out how to get scroll view to center the other views when paging.

.contentMargins(.horizontal, 40.0, for: .scrollContent)

@BerryBlue How about using the viewAligned behaviour? See the edit.
